# Datetime diffrence with rounding off in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I've two date and time. One is current datetime 
EX: 2015-5-5 3:30:34  - Time1, 2015-5-6 9:30:34   - Time 2.
Then after finding out, it needs to round off. How to do this??
Please help.

Comment: what do youmean by round off ??

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: Do you mean you need to find the difference between the two times? What's wrong with the Carbon functions like `diffInDays()`?

Comment: By using the diffInDays() , 'im getting only the difference between the days only. but i need the output like x days y hours z minute w seconds.For ex: if the the seconds exceeds 59 then it needs to round off to 1 minute and add to minute.